# Displaying the array elements one by one in a form in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am building an application using Angular js and Taffy Db.

I have got a resultset from Taffy DB which is an an array.

I want to display the elements one by one in my HTML page.

javascript:

```
$scope.viewList = function () {
    $scope.sharelists = [];
    $scope.resultSet = teamlist().get();
    var teamdata = $scope.resultSet;
    var length = teamdata.length;
    angular.forEach(teamdata, function (teamdata, i) {
        if (i < length) {
            console.log(i);
            $scope.teamlistresult = teamdata.text;
            $scope.sharelists.push({
                text: $scope.teamlistresult
            });
        }
    });
};
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="sharedby">Shared by</label>
<input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="View" ng-click="viewList()" />
         <ul class="unstyled">
      <li ng-repeat="share in sharelist">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="share.done">
        <span>{{share.text}}</span>         
      </li>
    </ul>
```

But I couldnt display the array elements one by one.

Please advice

Comment: The object to lookup in your markup says `sharelist`. The one in your script however, has a name of `sharelists`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if this method

`$scope.resultSet = teamlist().get();` is async and returns promise then you should use

```
teamlist().get().then(function(data) {
    var teamdata = data;
    var length = teamdata.length;
    angular.forEach(teamdata, function (teamdata, i) {
        if (i < length) {
            console.log(i);
            $scope.teamlistresult = teamdata.text;
            $scope.sharelists.push({
                text: $scope.teamlistresult
            });
        }
    });
}
```